# Question about Mobius function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}.$ I would know if is it true that $$-\underset{k\mid N}{\sum}\mu\left(k\right)\log\left(k\right)>0.$$I know that $$-\mu\left(k\right)\log\left(k\right)=\underset{r\mid k}{\sum}\mu\left(r\right)\Lambda\left(\frac{k}{r}\right)$$ but I don't think is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose that $N = p_1 \cdots p_\ell$, where $p_i \neq p_j$ are primes. We can identify a factor of $N$ with a subset of $\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$, say through a mapping $\varphi$. Then $\mu(\varphi(A)) = (-1)^{|A|}$ and $\log\varphi(A) = \sum_{i \in A} \log p_i$. Therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k|N} \mu(k) \log k &=
\sum_{A \subseteq \{1,\ldots,\ell\}} (-1)^{|A|} \sum_{i \in A} \log p_i \\ &=
\sum_{i=1}^\ell \log p_i \sum_{B \subseteq \{1,\ldots,\ell\} \setminus \{i\}} (-1)^{|B|+1} \\ &= \begin{cases} -\log p_1 & \text{if }\ell = 1, \\ 0 & \text{if }\ell \neq 1. \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Maybe is a dumb question, but why $N$ is necessary squarefree?

Comment: Bcause, if not, $\mu(N)=0$ anyway.

Comment: @Elajan It's not, but if you replace $N$ with its squarefree part then you'll get the same sum, since the Moebius function is supported on squarefree numbers. Take it as an exercise to argue this formally.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $m\ge 1$, and $N$ has more than $m$ distinct prime factors, we have
$$
\sum_{k\mid N}\mu(k)\log^m(k)=0.
$$
This can be easily seen by induction.